# Ruby Regex find numbers not surrounded by alphabetical characters

Tags: ruby, regex, sublimetext3

What I'm looking to do is to highlight numbers that aren't in the middle of a word.
The `001` in the following example should *not* highlight:

`FrontSprite=trainer001b`

But the `80` should in this example:

`BaseMoney=80`

Essentially, what this would mean is that any number should be highlighted **if it is preceded or followed by a number**.

I've been struggling a lot with this one. I'm very new to Regex and really can't find a working solution. This Regex would be used in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: `\b\d+\b`? Did you do any research? There are a lot of examples of this on stackoverflow and I see a new question identical to yours everyday.

Comment: `if it isn't preceded or followed by a number` - you mean by a non number? It's kinda hard to find a number that isn't a number

Comment: I've definitely done a lot of research. I just must've been using improper search tags. Thank you for your answer; works fine.

Comment: `\D*\d+\D*` would come to my mind.

Comment: @Jan, Actually, that is not correct. You meant `(^|\D)\d+(\D|$)` or `(^|\D)\d+(?!\d)` or `(?<!\d)\d+(?!\d)`